# My program cannot detect referred jar

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

[this is my projects's hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2Vwb.jpg)

I'm currently doing a project, and one of the function is to play videos. 
So, i'm using dsj.jar to play the videos..

It works perfectly when running using eclipse, but after export it into .jar,
the video won't play.

So, i guess, i don't have problem in defining the resource path or import the jar
(built path -> add external jar).

But why the video won't play after I export it into runnable jar?

Comment: The path in which it looks might be not what you think. The relative path to the jar might be different from the relative path within the project. Not sure if this is the case here, but it might be. Have you tried printing out the path in which it looks for the file?

Comment: You meant the directory of the file? I used system out to see the directory and it works correctly. I even tried to run the code in other computer (run using eclipse).. I used URL url = getClass().getResource("resources/xxxx.avi"); to get the file

Comment: And that resources directory is in the same folder as your jar file?

Comment: Yes... It is in the same folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your jar outside eclipse, you need to specify the classpath, i.e. the jars that your jar depends on.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)

Comment: The commands given is for executing using cmd right? Or i can use the same in eclipse, in classes?